# Django query annotation without timezone

Tags: django, postgresql, timezone, annotate

I'm trying to write the following query using Django's query objects:

```
all_proposals2 = Proposal.objects.raw(
"select *, vote_score/extract('epoch' from age(created)) as display_rank from proposals_proposal")
```

This is what I've come up with:

```
all_proposals = Proposal.objects.annotate(
    display_rank=F('vote_score') / Extract(Func(F('created'), function='AGE'), 'epoch'),
)
```

But it generates this query:

```
SELECT
   "proposals_proposal"."id",
   ...
   ("proposals_proposal"."vote_score" / 
      EXTRACT('epoch' FROM AGE("proposals_proposal"."created") AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles')) AS "display_rank" 
FROM
   "proposals_proposal" 
ORDER BY
   "proposals_proposal"."created" ASC
```

Which is not a valid query. Postgres gives this error:

```
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

But it is very close to correct except it has the extra `AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles'` appended to the `AGE()` function invokation. How can I change the query so that it doesn't have this timezone specification?

Comment: Have you tried `USE_TZ = False`?

Comment: Setting `USE_TZ=False` does fix the query but I want the timezone in all the other places where it's relevant. In this query, it's applying the timezone to an interval which should never have a timezone.

Answer (score 2):

After looking through the [source code for the `Extract` function](https://github.com/django/django/blob/8ed6788aa479034a44a8aa87da47de56dd728c95/django/db/backends/postgresql/operations.py#L66) that is applying this timezone rule, I realized that I would have to write this Extract call with the general `Func` instead.

```
    all_proposals = Proposal.objects.annotate(
        display_rank=ExpressionWrapper(F('vote_score') / Func(
            Func(F('created'), function='AGE'),
            function='EXTRACT',
            template='%(function)s(epoch from %(expressions)s)',
        ), output_field=FloatField()),
    )
```

This bypasses any automatic timezone specification.